# Common architecture for social registration with Facebook

Tags: facebook

Im just diving into the logic behind social login.

So far I geted the idea of creating a user authentification using the Facebook API.

The point which confusing me is the logical architecture of an web-app/-portal which uses social login for the user registration. When facebook returns to the site "logged into facebook" what should this website do now? Creating a new user entry in its own user database or something? And when the user is comming back and login in with FB again, should the website get the user-name and email from the facebook response and should compare the local user-database with some entries (before requesting the database for entry-data just based on the plaintext-user-name from FB)?

You see, Ive got no idea about the common architecture of such a login-solution. I dont even know the basic mechanisms of reading and storing users in a database in a proper way (getting user-informations just by a plain-text username or email as the key sounds very unsafe for me).

I know its a very abstract question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good answer is "it depends on your use case".

### Logged into facebook

- Some applications want to have their own user accounts. After logging in you can ask them to pick their username and password.
- Some applications want complimentary information. After logging in you can ask the user for more information.
- Some applications don't want or don't need any additional information. After the user has signed into Facebook, you show them the logged in view.
- You don't authenticate the user with their Facebook email, you authenticate them with their UID. Emails change, uids do not.

### What to store.

- Typically you create a local user which holds a reference to the Facebook uid.
- If you have a need for specific data like email and name, you would copy those into your local user account. The users access_token will expire after a while so you may need to keep a local reference.
- If your app is only interacting with Facebook and doesn't really have state on it's own, you don't need to save anything locally.
- If you need to keep requesting information about the user from Facebook after authenticating you would store their access_token, but it will expire if the user stops using your app.

### On overwriting user edited data.

- If the user edits fields on their local account you shouldn't overwrite that information because the user has intentionally overriden it. To make the data roll-back, would be confusing. If you are merely holding a local reference to their Facebook information, then by all means update it but don't present it in a manner where they can edit it.
- If you want to allow the user to both have local data and need to reference their Facebook data you could keep both `user.email` and `user.facebook.email` fields.

Comment: I see, very nice listing of facts, thank you! But Ive got one more point: If you just using Facebook to get the information of a person and create a new record based on that data in your own DB of users you can associate anytime the additional data when a user logs into with the uid -get it so far. But how can I get rid of „hackers“ who looks into the JS-Code and doing a DB request with a different UID which is not their own? After all I will have some lines of code In my sourcecode, which doing a DB-request with the UID variable (if I understand you right with your fourth list entry up there)

Comment: @MarcM Right you have to use the users access_token to request who they are. We always send users through the OAuth2 flow, which gets us an access_token and then we use that to get their details. Even if you're almost entirely a frontend app you still need to pass an access_token to the backend to verify who the user is. You also get it while doing the JS SDK login check, so you could pass it back: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus I just meant the `uid` is FB canonical representation of a user and everything refs that, you still have to verify it.